# Run function2 after function1 is complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My controller consists of a function that makes two function calls to the service with some scope values gathered from the view.

```
$scope.sendValues = function () {
    MyService.function1($scope.value1, $scope.value2);

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.arr.length; i++) {
        $scope.value3 = $(".input" + i).val();
        MyService.function2($scope.value3);
    }
};
```

Both the service functions makes a http request and they look similar to this:

```
var tempID = 0;

var function1 = function (value1, value2) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "someUrl",
        data: {
            valeu1: value1,
            value2: value2
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        tempID = response.data.id;
    });
};
```

Now the second function needs the value "tempID" from function1.

```
var function2 = function (value3) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "anotherURL",
        data: {
            value3: value3,
            tempID: tempID
        }
   });
};
```

The problem is that sometimes function2 runs before function1 is done, which results in tempID being the declared value of 0. How do i make sure function1 is done before function2 runs? i'm aware i can put function2 in function1 ones success/done, but then how do i get the view values which im looping through in the controller function.

Comment: Why not just have `function2` receive the entire POST response, so that it can get any data it likes from the transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of promises

```
var function1 = function (value1, value2) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "someUrl",
        data: {
           valeu1: value1,
           value2: value2
       }
   }).then(function (response) {
       tempID = response.data.id;
       retrun tempID;
   });
};

var function2 = function (value3, tempID) {
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "anotherURL",
    data: {
        value3: value3,
        tempID: tempID
    }
 });
};
```

You will call like this

```
function1('some value1', 'some value2').then(function(id){
     function2('your value 3', id).then(function(resp){
          // whatever you want to do with this response
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Callback is asynchronous in nature. It is obvious that sometimes 2 will run before 1. To solve the problem, include these functions into closures. Closures will execute these functions in order i.e. synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. But for elegance, promises, callbacks could be a better design.

```
var function1 = function (value1, value2) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "someUrl",
        data: {
            valeu1: value1,
            value2: value2
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        tempID = response.data.id;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.arr.length; i++) {
        $scope.value3 = $(".input" + i).val();
        MyService.function2($scope.value3);
        }
    });
};
```